# Inability to logout using keyboard

Tags: feature-request, logout, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't log out using just the keyboard.

On one instance I was using a laptop for which the touchpad was on the blink and I didn't have a mouse handy. Given that the **logout** link is hidden inside the arrow and available only on hover, I could not reach the link by repeatedly pressing `Tab`.

I borrowed a mouse just to log out, but seriously...

Comment: @oded thanks, but I do honestly think it is a bug that the site is not as accessible as it should be.

Comment: The [meta-tag:bug] tag should be used for software not working correctly, not for features not present.

Comment: I know, but - oh well, this could go on forever so I'll let it go, bug/feature-request is not a major issue anyway.

Comment: I agree with @Oded here. There is no rule that site must allow logout via keyboard only same way sites don't have to support logout by voice only. Mouse is integral part of browsing.

Comment: You did not just compare voice to keyboard input.... that is borderline trolling to me.

Comment: I was just being extreme, yeah.. but hope you get my point? Anyway asking to add such support is valid, there are several keyboard shortcuts in place already.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I was just as passive about all of this as the OP, thinking he shrugged stuff off quite well, but _'Mouse is integral part of browsing'_ is utter nonsense and quite frankly an annoying assertion. The mouse isn't even an integral part of the computer! Honestly...

Comment: @GrantThomas maybe I was overreacting, it's just that for me mouse is integral part guess I was wrong to assume the same for others.

Comment: Well, it's settled now, so chill guys. I got the point, we have a new feature, I can at least log out should I ever have a public terminal where the mouse is not working, etc etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a keyboard only, or any other device which you cannot locate the logout link, then simply append `/users/logout` to the exchange.com that you are currently on.

Or, for convenience: ***[`logout`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout)***

Feature-implemented.

Comment: Well this prequisites the knowledge about routing rules of SE, I think it's rather a workaround then a solution.